# Inner div inside flex not filling whole space

Tags: css, flexbox

I am creating a layout using css flexbox

Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/MurWade/pen/zGKbEM)

I have a flex div with `max-width:300px`.

And inside that div, i have another div with `width:100%`.

**But the inner div does not take up the whole 300px width unless I fill it with content**. So percentage does not work inside flex? Please help and improve this question for others

I only want the sidebar to be visible when there is something inside the sidebar. For example when I had a div in it with width 100% it should take up that 300px space.

Thank you!

Comment: you have given  max-width: 300px;, thats why its taking 300 px only when you added content..

Comment: please read my comment on @luthando Loot answer

Answer (score 0):

You should have :

```
 .halobi-sidebar {  
  background-color: green;
  width: 300px;
 }
```

Instead of this:

```
max-width: 300px;
```

if you use `max-width` then your inner div will only become `300px` if the parent div's content is long enough to fill up `300px`

Comment: But this will always show the sidebar. I only want it to be visible when there is something inside the sidebar. for example when i had a div with width 100% it should take up that 300px space. so i am expecting it to sort of work like a div with `position:relative;`

Comment: if you do not want the sidebar to be always visible, then it is okay to use `max-width`, please try setting the `min-height` of the inner div to `1px`.like this `<div style='width: 100%;min-height: 1px; background-color:red;' >`

Comment: still not working as expected. looks like percentage is not taking any effect when you are inside a flex item. thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The sidebar doesn't have any width set. Therefore it gets its width from the content inside it. When you say `width: 100%` it means 100% of the [computed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/computed_value) width of the parent element.

When there is no content within the sidebar, the computed width is 0 and the width of the child div is 100% of 0. When there is a little text in the child div, the computed width might be 220px and the child div would also be 220px.

You would see the same behaviour with a floated or positioned element as their default width without any content would also be 0. A statically positioned div with the default block display has a default width of 100%.

Why not use the `:empty` selector?

```css
.halobi-sidebar {  
  background-color: green;
  width: 300px;
}
.halobi-sidebar:empty {  
  display: none;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waoKgz

Another option is to set the 300px with on children elements instead of the sidebar itself:

```css
.halobi-sidebar {  
  background-color: green;
}
.halobi-sidebar > * {  
  width: 300px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOBvWQ

Comment: your second option could be a workaround. i think i might accept this as the answer. but why does adding a div with 100% width inside a flex item div not cover the whole space.